# Disadvantage to minimizing the summed squared errors as opposed to each observation's error?

Tags: optimization

A nonlinear objective function takes 1,000,000 parameters and outputs errors for ~1,000,000 observations. This objective function can either be written to output each of the 1,000,000 squared errors or a single summed squared error.

If using a gradient based optimization strategy that requests a Jacobian, the Jacobian for the objective function that outputs all errors would output ~8 terabytes whereas the objective function that outputs a single summed squared error would output ~8 megabytes.

Is there any reason why I wouldn't use the objective function that outputs a single summed squared error?

Comment: Are you asking why use SGD rather than GD?

Comment: No, I don't believe so (unless I'm misunderstanding the concepts). I'm wondering if the massive amount of additional information contained in the Jacobian for the objective function that outputs each error is beneficial to a minimization algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question so I tried to make a simple example (will format properly if this makes any sense):

Suppose we have a dataset of n observations D

Summed error

J(theta,D)=s (1)
Where s is some scalar

Non-summed error

J(theta)=v=[j(theta,D_1),...,j(theta,D_n)] (2)

Where v is some vector each entry of which is the loss for the ith observation in the data

We ultimately want to use the gradient of the loss function to change theta.  I don't see how we can use the Jacobian of (2), which will be a matrix, since theta is a vector in this case.